# Android Gradle merged Values.xml uses wrong namespace

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In the process of converting a project to the Android build system I get this error whenever I attempt to compile.

`Gradle: Error parsing XML: prefix must not be bound to one of the reserved namespace names`

The merged values.xml file contains the following root element:

`<resources xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">`

What is the cause of this error and how can it be fixed?

Comment: did you found the answer for this?

Comment: i have the same question

Comment: Did you figure this out?
Are there more error message after the one you posted?

Comment: I just ran into this tonight. same exact issue. its weird because the namespace doesn't exist in any of the files. gradle seems to be adding them to some... did the accepted answer really solve it for you?

Comment: I am having the same issue, not using any namespace but still stuck at this error.

Comment: I got the same issue, but the problem was in crashlytics plugin. Maybe you have something similar. This is a solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/31162685/957954

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just spent around 2 hours digging through the Git commit that broke our Gradle build. This commit contained over 200 changed files with 4000+ modified lines. You can imagine how much fun it was ;)

Anyway, here is what caused this obscure Gradle error for us: Some styles with a `xmlns:custom` attribute were defined in `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="content" xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/content</item>
</style>
```

As you can see the `custom` namespace is not even used. For some reason the Ant and ADT builds did not care about this attribute, but the Gradle `:processDebugResources` task barfed with a not very helpful error message.

Removing `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` fixed it.

Versions used: Gradle 1.10 and `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.0'`

Comment: I tried this as well but using `cordova build android` means that the values.xml get's overwritten on build with the same custom ns :(

Comment: I had same issue when I was porting Eclipse based project (ANT) to Android Studio (Gradle). The problem was due to Crashlytics that was having same format of `<style name="ns0" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">`. Problem solved by deleting the file (I'll add crashlytics back once my porting is done).

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue. Mine was due to Crashlytics. Their automatically generated xml file has invalid name spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Read all my answer first : it seems that this error is due to another compilation problem...

Initially, to deal with this error, I updated my code like this:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">
 ...
</resources>
```

into this code:

```
<resources ignore="MissingTranslation">
     ...
</resources>
```

And it works for me at the beginning...but I had another compilation error due tu gradle configuration...and now that these compilation errors are corrected, my previous update does not work anymore. I had to add the namespace to generate the APK file.

So , be sure to correct all the compilation errors first before to deal with this error...

Answer (score 2):

mine was close to all of this. Someone had declared a name space inside of a strings tag.  Something like this:

```
<string name="google_play" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >Google Play</string>
```

i obviously removed the ns reference as it should not be there like that.  I had to search the entire codebase for the word "xmlns:" and look for one that was in the wrong place. Took a while.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue while syncing with Firebase. It was due to analytics package dependency in the app level gradle. It was solved by commenting/ removing

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when i updated Android studio 1.5 to 2.2 version. A quick solution to this is when u open existing project in updated version, just 'ignore' the update gradle plugin/version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i found the following code within the styles.xml

```
 <item name="android:listSelector">
                <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                    <item android:drawable="@color/pressed_color" android:state_pressed="true" />
                    <item android:drawable="@color/focused_color" android:state_focused="true" />
                    <item android:drawable="@color/item_list_color" />
                </selector>
            </item>
```

In selector exists a error

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

I removed the code above and solve my problem