# Android - The prefix "xmlns" cannot be bound to any namespace explicitly; neither can the namespace for "xmlns" be bound to any prefix explicitly

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle, xml-namespaces

Is anyone getting this "xmlns" namespace issue (see below)? I cannot build my work project anymore.

- At first I thought it was my git branch, so I switched to the origin develop and master branches - issue persists.
- I cleaned and rebuilt my project - issue persists.
- I cleaned and synched my grade files - issue persists.
- Finally I tried re-installing Android Studio and re-creating my git repository - issue persists.

  ```
  The prefix "xmlns" cannot be bound to any namespace explicitly; neither can the namespace for "xmlns" be bound to any prefix explicitly.
  Error: The prefix "xmlns" cannot be bound to any namespace explicitly; neither can the namespace for "xmlns" be bound to any prefix explicitly.
  :{project}:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
  Execution failed for task ':{project}:mergeReleaseResources'.
  > {project}/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeResources/release/merger.xml:1:61: Error: The prefix "xmlns" cannot be bound to any namespace explicitly; neither can the namespace for "xmlns" be bound to any prefix explicitly.
  ```

Note: Issue seems similar to [Android Gradle merged Values.xml uses wrong namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19526945/1877798), but I couldn't find an unused namespace. I ran an inspect, but no unused namespaces were found.

Comment: If you are trying to integrate Fabric/Crashlytics then what helped me is ditching IDE plugin and adding it manually following this guide: https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/android/integrating

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In my case deleting the **com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml** file fixed this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<resources>
<!--
  This file is automatically generated by Crashlytics to uniquely 
  identify individual builds of your Android application.

  Do NOT modify, delete, or commit to source control!
-->
<string xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/tools" name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id" ns0:ignore="UnusedResources,TypographyDashes" translatable="false">xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: That makes sense... I recently migrated from using crashlytics w/o fabric.io to crashlytics w/ fabric.io. It was working then, but maybe something creeped in between branches.

Comment: Is thi sfile not gnereated on each build though? So simply deleting the file doesnt really solve the issue.

Comment: I added:

`preBuild << {
    delete('src/main/res/values/com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml')
}`

in my build.gradle to at least automate the clearing of it, although I do agree the issue should be fixed on their end really.

Comment: Thanks @Michael , you save my day

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove all **xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"** from your **main\res\values\style.xml** file **style** tag. 
Your **style.xml** file should be like this: (make sure no xmlns field in your style tag)

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>

    <style name="RadioButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton">
        <item name="android:button">@null</item>
        <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clear this error by 'editing' my build.gradle fine (delete a space, etc) and ***THEN*** cleaning my build. Without first editing the gradle build file, Android Studio was not picking up the changes.