# xmlns namespace issue while importing Eclipse Project in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, gradle, xml-namespaces

I had imported an Eclipse project in Android Studio and all files and dependencies seems to have generated.Whenever I try to run the project, I get an error saying:

```
C:\Users\Android_Dev1\Documents\xxxx\xxxxxxxx\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeResources\debug\merger.xml:1:61: Error: The prefix "xmlns" cannot be bound to any namespace explicitly; neither can the namespace for "xmlns" be bound to any prefix explicitly.
:xxxx:mergeDebugResources FAILED
```

The **values.xml** opens up with the erroneous line:

```
<resources xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">
```

I tried [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221236/android-the-prefix-xmlns-cannot-be-bound-to-any-namespace-explicitly-neithe) and [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526945/android-gradle-merged-values-xml-uses-wrong-namespace), but I neither have crashlytics or `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in **styles.xml**

This is my **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    // compile project(':google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':library-tabswipe')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.1'
}
```

I have also tried compiling the **appcompatv7 lib**, but the issue is same. Where am I going wrong? Why is the values.xml sad?

Comment: could it be a name conflict? I would try changing `ns1` for another less ordinary

Comment: @JuanAguilarGuisado how do you suggest to do that?

Comment: something like : <resources xmlns:customMyNameSpace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">