# Error:The prefix "xmlns" cannot be bound to any namespace explicitly to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-studio-import

I am getting below error while importing the eclipse code to Android studio.
I am not getting why this is happening
I have already tried for possible solutions by checking XMLNS and other custom tags.

[image: This is file where it navigates for error - this is auto-generated file]

[image: This is error I'm getting]

Comment: remove `<eat-comment>`

Comment: @MD This is auto-generated file,I can not make any edit in this file

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526945/android-gradle-merged-values-xml-uses-wrong-namespace and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221236/android-the-prefix-xmlns-cannot-be-bound-to-any-namespace-explicitly-neithe ?

Comment: @RajeshJadav yes I gone through it but there is no such things in my project display in that 2 questions

Answer (score 2):

Remove all **xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"** in your **main\res\values\style.xml** file from **style** tag. 
Here is is the sample code:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>

    <style xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" name="RadioButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton">
        <item name="android:button">@null</item>
        <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    </style>

    <style xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" name="EditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

It should be like this:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>

    <style name="RadioButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton">
        <item name="android:button">@null</item>
        <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```