# Grade Error parsing XML: prefix must not be bound to one of the reserved namespace names

Tags: android, xml, gradle, merge

I was working on my project when I have updated the Android Studio to version  AI-141.2024585.

Everything worked well before upgrading, but then the project didn't compile.
I have this error **Error: (3) Error parsing XML: prefix must not be bound to one of the reserved namespace names**
And this is the file values.xml with error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">
    <declare-styleable name="DragSortListView"><attr format="dimension" name="collapsed_height"/><attr format="color" name="float_background_color"/><attr format="float" name="float_alpha"/><attr format="integer" name="remove_animation_duration"/><attr format="integer" name="drop_animation_duration"/><attr format="float" name="slide_shuffle_speed"/><attr format="boolean" name="remove_enabled"/><attr name="remove_mode"><enum name="clickRemove" value="0"/><enum name="flingRemove" value="1"/></attr><attr format="integer" name="fling_handle_id"/><attr format="integer" name="click_remove_id"/><attr format="boolean" name="drag_enabled"/><attr name="drag_start_mode"><enum name="onDown" value="0"/><enum name="onMove" value="1"/><enum name="onLongPress" value="2"/></attr><attr format="integer" name="drag_handle_id"/><attr format="float" name="drag_scroll_start"/><attr format="float" name="max_drag_scroll_speed"/><attr format="boolean" name="track_drag_sort"/><attr format="boolean" name="use_default_controller"/><attr format="boolean" name="sort_enabled"/></declare-styleable>

    <eat-comment/>
    <string name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id" ns1:ignore="UnusedResources,TypographyDashes" translatable="false" ns1:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/tools">0000000000000000</string>
</resources>
```

I've tried installing a stable version of Android Studio and updating gradle.
I also searched the ns1 attribute in the entire project but only appears in that file.

Being a generated file can not change it, but I can modify the library.
Do you know how to fix the error? Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the same build for Android Studio. Couldn't find the com_crashlytics xml file. Are you using crashlytics? It's strange that I'm getting the same issue but I'm not using crashlytics.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because of crashlytics plugin. You may try to delete any crashltics-generated xml files in every modules, Then re-sync the gradle file of your app.

The crashltics-generated xml files looks like  `[ModuleXYZ]/src/res/values/com_crashlytics_xxx.xml`

And Crashlytics seems to release an update you should also update the plugin.

**Update** After successfully building my project with procedure above it could happen again, it happened twice yesterday. Not sure why but just follow the procedure above it'll be fixed.

Comment: That is the solution. Just deleting the file com_crashlytics_xxx.xml has already worked, but also I have updated the plugin. Thanks a lot

Comment: For my case, I'm not using crashlytics, and this still happens. Does the 1.3 update already include it. I'm confused. Also, I can't seem to find the com_crashlytics xml you mentioned.

Comment: @Harold.Hernandez If you're not using crashlytics you won't find com_crashtytics_xx.xml anywhere. Maybe you should check if there's any plugins used in the project misbehaved.

Comment: Thanks @Robert. Will try to find the culprit. Any tips on what may cause these: xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"?

Comment: `xmlns:ns1="w3.org/2000/xmlns/";` this should NOT be the culprit. There should be other errors highlighted in the xml file and that could be the actual cause.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and as Robert said the problem can be fixed deleting all the `com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml` files.

Also make sure in your build.gradle the crashlytics version is 2.4.0+ and the corrupteds files won't be generated again.

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. 

We shipped out an updated version of the plugins that has a fix for this. If you update to the latest version then this will be all set.

Comment: @MikeB using plugin version 2.2.1 and still facing with the problem, i just installed the plugin it is the latest version right?